# Will hackers be able to view the value of a hidden field

Tags: .net, html, security

I want to call a web service using javaScrip but the web service call contains user name and password, so i am thinking of storing the values of the user name and password in a hidden fields , then to construct the web service URL using javaScript by appending the values of the username and password. Incase i am going to implment https for these web service calls , then will storing the values of the username and password as hidden fields inside the html page consider secure?

Comment: No! Anything on the client side will be visible to anyone who wants to see it. Proxy the web service on your server and then use JavaScript to make an AJAX request to your proxy instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Absolutely yes**, hackers will be able to see the value of the hidden field. Hidden fields in HTML are easily visible, to anyone who looks at the page source.

To show this, here is a bit of code from the google log in page.

```
<form id="gaia_loginform"
      action="https://www.google.com/LoginAction2?service=mail" method="post"
      onsubmit="return(gaia_onLoginSubmit());">
<div id="gaia_loginbox">
<table class="form-noindent" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="text-align:center" nowrap="nowrap"
        bgcolor="ddf8cc">
  <input type="hidden" name="ltmpl"
             value="default">
  <input type="hidden" name="ltmplcache"
             value="2">
```

Notice this in particular:

Hidden means it doesn't show up on the web page, but is still included in the source. All someone would have to do would be to navigate to the page, look at the source, and they could find any hidden entries.

Comment: so what other approaches i can follow to be able to set and send the master login username and password with web service call using javaScript ..?

Comment: It depends on your architecture really. But you want to do the verification on the server side in general.

Answer (score 2):

Yes any client can see it and no it's not secure. You just have to view a page's source and even a hidden `<input>`'s value is visible.

Answer (score 2):

It's secure if the attacker is listening on the network. Properly used HTTPS prevents him from learning anything useful. This is the correct thread model if the username/password are the pair identifying the browser's user. It's not the correct model if the username/password pair identifies you(the server operator) to a third party.

It's insecure if you consider the user the enemy. He can simply ask his browser to give him the value of the hidden fields, or he can sniff the SSL connection(For example using javascript, or hooking the SSL libs, or having his SSL libs emit the key to a log file). You can't keep any information you send to the client secret from him.

In practice this means you should verify the client using the user's session ID, and using the server to connect to external APIs.

Comment: I hesitate to start out an answer to anything this bad as "It's secure", even if reading the whole thing shows that it really isn't...